# Nuxt Auth0 $auth.loggedIn false user data null

Tags: node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex, auth0

I been following this example
https://github.com/nuxt/example-auth0

Not sure why i can't get $auth.loggedIn to return true, and user data is not set in vuex
[image]

Here is my nuxt config

```
      auth: {
    redirect: {
      login: '/', // redirect user when not connected
      callback: '/'
    },
    strategies: {
      local: false,
      auth0: {
        domain: process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN,
        client_id: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID
      }
    }
  }
```

my navbar.vue

```
    <b-navbar-nav class="ml-4 ml-md-auto">
      <b-nav-item class="mr-3" v-if="$store.state.auth.loggedIn" @click="$auth.logout()">Sign Off</b-nav-item>
      <b-nav-item class="mr-3" v-else @click="$auth.loginWith('auth0')">Sign In</b-nav-item>
    </b-navbar-nav>
<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'    
export default {
  computed: mapGetters(['isAuthenticated'])
}
</script>
```

Any idea what do i miss? i tested https://github.com/nuxt/example-auth0 it's working fine just not on my project :/

Comment: Did you do the Auth0 config properly on the dashboard? What does your network tab telling you?

Comment: Yes i did i put the same domain and clientID credentials in the example repo, it works fine there, but my project it only work until after i login, there is no error or anything when redirected to auth0 login screen, just $auth.loggedIn return false, and user data is null :/ i feel like it might be vuex not storing data properly or something, i've check my vuex config i copy exact the same from the example repo.  Network tab any idea what i should be looking for? i tested on example repo and my project doesnt seem to return anything after auth0 login thanks really appreciete

Comment: I'm curious: is your nuxt app ssr or spa? also, does the $auth.loggedIn stay as false after a refresh?